# Error when importing jszip in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, jszip

When importing jzsip into my typescript component file, I get an error.

I have run npm install jszip, and the package appears to be properly installed. However, when I import the package with

```
import * as JSZip from 'jszip';
```

I get the following error message:

---

Error: node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts:72:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'AbortSignal' must be of type '{ new (): AbortSignal; prototype: AbortSignal; abort(reason?: any): AbortSignal; timeout(milliseconds: number): AbortSignal; }', but here has type '{ new (): AbortSignal; prototype: AbortSignal; }'.

72 declare var AbortSignal: {
~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:2071:13
2071 declare var AbortSignal: {
'AbortSignal' was also declared here.

---

I am using:
Angular version 15.1.1
Typescript version 4.9.6
jszip 3.10.1

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51567

Comment: cheers, that thread lead me to the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try typescript 4.8.4. It's recommanded for Angular 15

Answer (score 0):

Try with TypeScript 4.7.2 and try:

```
import * as JSZip from 'jszip';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

download() {
    const j: JSZip = new (<any>JSZip).default();

    j.file('Hello.txt', 'Hello World\n');

    j.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' }).then(function (content) {
      // see FileSaver.js
      saveAs(content, 'example.zip');
    });
  }
```

Remember install: `npm i file-saver` to save file.
Checkout: [JSZip example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nsa5bc?file=package.json,src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding @types/node to my dev dependencies:

```
npm i -d @types/node
```